# Index/key on three fields or concat() fields into another column

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, primary-key, concatenation

My community website will take registrations from residents via a registration form which will have three list boxes for Block, Floor number and Door number.

My first question is - Since I would need to retrieve the apartment number for some operations, will storing the three fields in three different columns slow down the retrieval of data/reports? Would it be a better idea to add another field to the table that stores the concatenated value and use that for retrieval?

My second question is: If I were to go the concatenation route, would it make a difference whether I concatenated them before sending to the database (in the processing php) or if I set the column in the table such that it took the three values in the table and performed the concat?

**EDIT**

Based on the responses, a little explanation might add value here:

My form/table is meant for comments and suggestions by members. Querying the table could be:

1. By members to check the status of their complaint. There could potentially be say 20 such calls a day - rarely more than this.
2. By the admin calling for reports from the admin page - this could be unanswered complaints, resolved complaints, sending thank-you notes for suggestions, etc. This could also mean getting unresolved complaints per block etc.
3. By the admin when he responds to the member - this will call an update to the record.
4. By members sending in new complaints or suggestions.

So, effectively, querying could be by individual apartment numbers or by block names. I already have a check-complaint-status form that uses the three column s separately and that isn't an issue as it involves retrieval of a single record. What if, say, there are 30 records that will turn up in a B-block report? Or a hundred? Will concatenation on retrieval be an issue in that scenario?

Comment: Having three fields and then another field with the same data as those three fields combined is just duplicating data. Concatenate them as needed.

Comment: Speed really shouldn't be an issue with a single registration...I'd choose where to concatenate based on where I most like to code ;)

Comment: I think that will be a matter of preference.  Me personally, an apartment number might be worth an additional database column.  Storing should not be slowed depending on how you query the information from the database and what fields are flagged as indexes.

Comment: Based on your edited response, the short answer is no - you shouldn't see any kind of slowdown. Indexing the individual rows will help with querying information.  It is when you are doing modifications (e.g INSERT and UPDATE statements) in a large batch where you see slowdowns.  This is due to the index files needing to be updated and depending on your DB size this could take more time than desired.

Answer (score 0):

**Q** will storing the three fields in three different columns slow down the retrieval of data/reports?

**A** No, it won't slow down retrieval, as long as the datatypes are suitable. (Use INT or VARCHAR, rather than longish CHAR. If it's easier for you to deal with the values concatenated when you retrieve them, then do the concatenation on retrieval.

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.block,'|',t.floor_number,'|',t.door_number) AS apartment_number
```

That won't slow anything down.

On the other hand, if you have no need to EVER query or update these individual fields, and you will always deal with it as just apartment_number... then you could just create a column for apartment_number.

Where performance is going to slow down is if you ever need to parse the individual fields out from apartment_number.  For example, if you needed to retrieve rows where the door number component is even, or where the floor number is greater than 1... that's when things are going to slow down.

I would store them as separate fields, so I could access the individual components if I ever needed to. For example, so I could answer questions like, how many door numbers on floor 2 of block 3?